# How to get one specific instance (e.g nth occurrance) of a Meeting Series using MS Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail, microsoft-graph-calendar

In MS EWS API, It was possible to get `nth instance` of a meeting series by providing series index.

We are migrating our EWS implementation to MS Graph. But I could not find an API to do the same.

I have found a different implementation to fetch all instances of meeting series with a date range.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-list-instances?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

But this new endpoint does not fit our implementation as our application and outlook calendar are out of sync by design. So, we don't have a definite start/end date to search for a single instance.

Is there an API or workaround to fetch nth instance of a meeting without providing date range.

Thanks in advance.